# ¿Como puedo hacer la Búsqueda en Anchura en Python?

Tags: python, json, while

Estoy implementando un método de búsqueda en anchura en lenguaje Python. Lo estoy utilizando para hallar el camino óptimo entre los nodos de un grafo, el detalle es que use un codigo que encontre de un foro y quiero saber si de los grafos de la imagen estan bien o le falta algo?.

Al ejecutarlo parace que esta bien el recorrido que hace al pedir un valor, tambien quisiera saber si se puede agregar el nodo deseado en el la busqueda en anchura. Dejo el codigo para saber si tengo algún elemento erróneo y que se puede mejorar:

El archivo json1:

```
{
 "A": [["B",2],["C",3],["C",4]],
 "B": [["A",1],["H",5],["I",6]],
 "C": [["A",1],["J",7],["K",8]],
 "D": [["A",1],["L",9]],
 "H": [["B",2],["O",10]],
 "I": [["B",2]],
 "J": [["C",3]],
 "K": [["C",3]],
 "L": [["D",4],["M",11],["N",12]],
 "M": [["L",9]],
 "N": [["L",9]],
 "O": [["H",5],["P",13],["Q",14]],
 "P": [["O",10]],
 "Q": [["O",10]]
}
```

O pueden usar el json de la imagen:

```
{
 "A": [["B",2]],
 "B": [["E",1],["G",4]],
 "C": [["A",3]],
 "D": [["C",1]],
 "E": [["F",2]],
 "F": [["H",1]],
 "G": [["D",2]],
 "H": [["G",1],["J",2],["I",2]],
 "I": [["H",2],["J",3]],
 "J": [["H",2],["I",3],["K",2]],
 "K": [["M",2],["L",3]],
 "L": [["K",3],["I",1]],
 "M": [["L",2]]
}
```

El codigo del programa:

```
from fileinput import close
import os
from pathlib import Path
import json
from ast import main
from collections import deque
#leer json

cola = deque()
JPATH = '.' #<---punto significa ruta actual
JNAME = 'ArbolV1.json'
def main():
r = 0
while r != 2:
      print("\n","*****BIENVENIDO A LA BUSQUEDA EN ANCHURA*****")
      Ruta = Path(JPATH)/JNAME
      if Ruta.exists():#Se  abre el archivo json solo para lectura
         with Ruta.open() as archivojson:
             ArbolV1 = json.load(archivojson)
             print("Se Muestra el grafo antes del recorrido: \n")
             #print(ArbolV1)
             for key, lista in ArbolV1.items():
                 print(key) 
                 print(lista)

             print()
             os.system("pause")
             visitados = []
             cola = []
             origen = input("Ingresa el nodo origen: ")
             print("\nLista de recorrido en lo ancho del arbol\n")
#Paso 1: SE COLOCA EL VÉRTICE ORIGEN EN UNA COLA
             cola.append(origen)
#Paso 2: MIENTRAS LA COLA NO ESTE VACÍA
             while cola:
#Paso 3: DESENCOLAR UN VÉRTICE, ESTE SERÁ AHORA EL VÉRTICE ACTUAL
                 actual = cola.pop(0)
#Paso 4: SI EL VÉRTICE ACTUAL NO HA SIDO VISITADO
                 if actual not in visitados:
#Paso 5: PROCESAR (IMPRIMIR) EL VÉRTICE ACTUAL
                    print("Vertice actual --> ", actual)
#Paso 6: COLOCAR VÉRTICE ACTUAL EN LA LISTA DE VISITADOS
                    visitados.append(actual)
#paso 7: PARA CADA VÉRTICE QUE EL VÉRTICE ACTUAL TIENE COMO DESTINO,
#        Y QUE NO HA SIDO VISITADO:
#        ENCOLAR EL VERTICE
                 for key, lista in ArbolV1[actual]:
                    if key not in visitados:
                        cola.append(key)
             print()
             os.system("pause")
             break

                 r=int(input())
          if r == 2:
             close  
     else:
    print("El archivo json no existe")

  if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: Descripcion del recorrido de grafos explicado]

Comment: Creo que debes ser más conciso en tu pregunta, no se entiende bien qué es lo que quieres preguntar.

Comment: Listo se modifico la pregunta y el texto de lo que necesito hacer